# Dictionary in Pandas DataFrame, how to split the columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` that consists of one `column` ('Vals') which is a `dictionary`. The `DataFrame` looks more or less like this:

```
In[215]: fff
Out[213]: 
                                                Vals
0    {u'TradeId': u'JP32767', u'TradeSourceNam...
1    {u'TradeId': u'UUJ2X16', u'TradeSourceNam...
2    {u'TradeId': u'JJ35A12', u'TradeSourceNam...
```

When looking at an individual `row` the `dictionary` looks like this:

```
In[220]: fff['Vals'][100]
Out[218]: 
{u'BrdsTraderBookCode': u'dffH',
 u'Measures': [{u'AssetName': u'Ie0',
   u'DefinitionId': u'6dbb',
   u'MeasureValues': [{u'Amount': -18.64}],
   u'ReportingCurrency': u'USD',
   u'ValuationId': u'669bb'}],
 u'SnapshotId': 12739,
 u'TradeId': u'17304M',
 u'TradeLegId': u'31827',
 u'TradeSourceName': u'xxxeee',
 u'TradeVersion': 1}
```

How can I split the the `columns` and create a new `DataFrame`, so that I get one column with `TradeId` and another one with `MeasureValues`?

Comment: I know you have described it verbally, however, can you show a sample of your desired output. That will help clarify a few things. You say "one row with TradeId and another one with MeasureValues" - you mean two separate rows? or one row with 2 columns? or one row with multiple columns for the possible Measure Values

Comment: I have edited the text above to clarify: I meant separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
l=[]

for idx, row in df['Vals'].iteritems():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(row['Measures'][0]['MeasureValues'])
    temp_df['TradeId'] =  row['TradeId']
    l.append(temp_df)

pd.concat(l,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get `TradeId` and `MeasureValues` (using twice your sample row above to illustrate the iteration):

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for id, data in fff.iterrows():
    d = {'TradeId': data.ix[0]['TradeId']}
    d.update(data.ix[0]['Measures'][0]['MeasureValues'][0])
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T])

  Amount TradeId
0 -18.64  17304M
0 -18.64  17304M
```

Comment: See updated answer to address your layout clarification.

Comment: That looks good, how can I simply get the value of the 'MeasureValue' instead of the [{'Amount'... ?

Comment: Do you need the column to be called `MeasureValues` with the value corresponding to `Amount`, or would `column` `name` `Amount` work?